# Why "green" for the Green Lanterns?

Tags: comics, dc, green-lantern, green-lantern-tas

Why did the original creator (Martin Nodell) of the Green Lantern choose the color green?

I'm looking for the **out-of-universe** explanation, which internet search is not giving me.

Was the choice driven by the limitations of comic printing technology of the 1940's?  Did Nodell give an interviews or comments as to the reason for the choice?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using Google, I came across this [Martin Nodell bio](http://web.archive.org/web/20100612073240/http://pabook.libraries.psu.edu/palitmap/bios/Nodell__Martin.html) link:

> Nodell was inspired by the Green Lantern idea by waiting for a New York subway, and he saw a train operator waving a **lantern with a green light**. According to USA Today, “Nodell imagined a young engineer, Alan Scott, a train crash survivor who discovers in the debris an ancient lantern forged from a green meteor. Scott constructs a ring from the lamp that gives him super powers and becomes a crime fighter.”
>
> In a 2000 interview with Bill Black, editor and publisher of AC Comics, Nodell said, “I picked out the name from the train man on the tracks who was waving a lantern, going from red to green…**green meant go and I decided that was it**."

Comment: I think the retcon was ingenious.

Comment: “he saw a train operator waving a lantern with a green light... Scott constructs a ring from the lamp that gives him super powers and becomes a crime fighter.” Scott should have just taken the lamp and got a low-effort, union-protected job for life!